# Antlr string matching order

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm triying to use ANTLR with a kind of file where the value to retrieve can be any sequence of chars excluding { and }.

```
text = {Valid;String}
text = {Another"Valid"-String}
```

But now VALUE is matching the line from the begining:

*line 1:0 mismatched input 'text = ' expecting 'text'*

What I'm doing wrong? Should not match with TEXT first?

```
grammar Example;

example : (TEXT '=' '{' VALUE '}')+;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

TEXT : 'text';

VALUE : ~('{'|'}')+;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Terence (The ANTLR Guy) mentioned, the rule `VALUE` greedily matches `text =`. You could let the `VALUE` rule include the braces instead of matching them as separate tokens:

```
example : (TEXT '=' VALUE)+;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

TEXT : 'text';

VALUE : '{' ~('{'|'}')+ '}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because ANTLR 4 will try to match the longest string so "text ..." will match to VALUE.